Can an optional catch-all flow cause duplicate calls?
It's not so much a problem as a question I haven't found an answer to. I have a project I am working on that is re-designing how a CMS (Bloomreach) is working. Essentially, we've restructured the project to be a NextJS app router application, and have a single entry structure.
app
- layout.tsx
- [[...route]]
-- page.tsx

It is currently set up to be SSG, so there is a set up to generateStaticProps so it'll build the pages out.
const getPage = cache(
  async ({ requestURL, tags }: { requestURL: string; tags: string[] }) => {
    return await fetchItem(requestURL, tags);
  },
);

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const pages = (await getWebsitePaths()) ?? [];
  return Array.from(new Set(pages)).map((url) => ({
    route: urlStringToArray(url),
  }));
}

export default async function Page({
  params,
}: {
  params: { route: string[] };
}) {
  let configuration;
  let commerceConfig;
  let pageModel;
  const route = params.route && params.route.length > 0 ? params.route : [''];

  const isPreview = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IS_PREVIEW === 'true';
  let pathname: string | null = paramCreation(route);

  const requestUrl = pathCheck(pathname, '');
  const tags = [mapCacheTag(pathname)];

  configuration = buildConfiguration(`${pathname}?`);
  pageModel = await getPage({ requestURL: requestUrl, tags });

  if (!pageModel || pageModel.status === 404) {
    notFound();
  }

  commerceConfig = loadCommerceConfig(pageModel);

  return (
    <BrxApp
      configuration={configuration!}
      page={pageModel}
      commerceConfig={commerceConfig!}
    />
  );
}

It does seem to be working as expected (in the sense it builds, starts, and can be navigate without issue).
The catch is there does appear to be 7 extra pages being build outside of my list, and the behavior seems to be duplicating the calls (even before this process).
I'm just trying to determine if this seems like normal behavior for an optional catch-all, or something that may be coming from the CMS package/design (it's proving difficult to troubleshoot the cause, and I am relatively new to NextJS/React as a whole)?

I have ensured that my fetch calls are limited (only those 2 listed in the code).
I've made sure my middleware isn't impacting it by removing it.
My main call (the fetchItem) is cached, so no worries about hitting the API too frequently.
And I do know the '!' are bad practice, I am still in the process of cleaning up a couple of things (along with the 'let', needs to be cleaned up as well).

Mainly, I just want to know if this is standard behavior with an optional catch-all, and any potential advice if it is.
